# Return Random Number but not 2

Tags: php, recursion, random

Why is it this sometimes returns 2?

```
function pickServer(){
    $varr = rand(1,4);
    if($varr==2){
        pickServer();
    }
    return $varr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, all correct, but I had to pick one only. :)

Comment: Actually most of them are missing the real problem (including the accepted answer). Don't use recursion as a Goto. 

Put a loop around the $var=rand(1,4) call until it returns a value !=2, don't call pickServer again inside this method. Think of the children! Think of your Stack Frame!

If you run this code and hit a streak of 2's you could theoretically create StackOverflow conditions and I ain't talking about a Q&A Wiki site.

Comment: Don't loop at all. Your random generation range is one too large--you don't see it because the number you want to exclude is inside the range. If it were at the beginning or end you wouldn't loop, so why loop just because it's in the middle? Remap.

Comment: +! JohnFX - Thank you. That's what I was just writing up. Many of these solutions may technically work but have the bad side effect of being both indeterminate *and* recursive (including the accepted answer). That is a dangerous combination that will turn into one of those illusive bugs that will crash your system randomly... once in awhile... for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Robert C. Cartaino, even if it's not recursive, there's still no reason for it to be indeterminate.

Comment: @Nosredna - I agree. The most *technically* correct answer would be to remap your random space to one that does not include "2". Then your method would execute in O(1) time. Looping inside the method is a quick, pragmatic approach which would solve the basic problem but isn't the best solution from an accademic standpoint. But I *do* agree with you that the method *shouldn't* be indeterminate and ***definitely*** not recursive.

Comment: @Nosredna - By the way, your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300797/return-random-number-but-not-2/1300895#1300895. Is the only completely correct answer and should have been "chosen."

Comment: @Robert. Thanks. I'm not sure why people pick the "correct" answer so quickly. :-) This one went in 4 minutes! Granted, the asker got some information quickly, and might have been all he wanted (clear up the confusion of how the "2" got through), but having the chosen answer keep the recursive theme is just...wild.

Comment: @Robert C. Cartaino: While Nosredna's answer explains the whole thing better than mine, I'd like to know what in my answer you find to be incorrect.

Comment: @Balpha Your answer is not bad. I upvoted you.

Comment: @Nosredna: That wasn't my intention, but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: yeah, I was going to add a note about how this isn't the best way to do what he wanted, but it's just picking a number between 1 and 4... the performance hit isn't going to be worth the time spent explaining and rewriting the code.

Comment: @balpha - Your first answer (with the recursion) is dangerous (even though you point out that there is no guarantee) so I didn't read carefully the rest of the post. Your second example works but I had to scratch my head for a second to figure out why. @Nosredna's answer was more direct (just my opinion). Like @Abs said; you can only pick one answer. But it's all good. You got my +1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you're not stopping the function there. the fourth line should read:

```
return pickServer();
```

Comment: This is still recursive and potentially dangerous. See the comment-discussion on the original question.

Comment: This is useful for answering the "why." But it results in a dreadful solution, as Robert points out.

Answer (score 27):

The answer to your question, as others have pointed out, is that your code falls through without returning. If `2` is returned by the call to rand() on both the first attempt *and* the second attempt (there's a 1/16 chance of this happening), you'll get `2` as a result.

But your approach to solving the problem could be better.

Both recursion and looping are barmy for this problem. This is a *mapping* problem, not a *randomness* problem. (It resembles some common randomness coding interview problems which can be handled most easily in a rejection loop, but it really isn't a problem of that class.)

You want one of **three** outcomes, not **four**. (1, 3, and 4.) That means you should be generating a range of three random numbers, not four. You could remap with an array or use an `if`. Both possibilities are shown below. Let me know if I have syntax wrong--my PHPfu is weak this morning.

```
/* array remapping */
function pickServer() {
    $remap = array(1, 3, 4);
    return $remap[rand(1,3)];
}

/* if remapping */
function pickServer() {
    $server = rand(1,3);
    if ($server==2) {
        $server=4;
    }
    return $server;
}
```

I didn't notice it before, but balpha anticipated my answer. He remapped with an `if` in his second example. Instead of remapping 2 to 4, he just added one to any answer above 1, which is an equivalent solution.

Comment: The syntax looks correct to me. Well done. *This* should have been the selected answer.

Comment: A true random RNG could return 2 forever. At least this will not get stuck in a loop.

Comment: I think you'll find that a true RNG always returns 4: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png

Comment: +1.  The original function and accepted answer are both criminally inefficient.  No matter how many "holes" are in your range, you can always generalize it as a mapping problem.

Answer (score 13):

Another way to do it is using `do … while`:

```
function pickServer() {
    do {
        $varr = rand(1,4);
    } while ($varr == 2);
    return $varr;
}
```

Comment: Arguably better since most languages don't optimize tail recursion and this is not any less clear than the recusive one.

Comment: Finally someone with some sense to point out that using recursion as a goto is crazy. +1

Comment: I think for the problem at hand, both recursion and looping are crazy. :-)

Comment: The second best answer, but far behind Nosrednas.

Answer (score 10):

What you probably want is

```
function pickServer(){
  $varr = rand(1,4);
  if($varr==2){
    $varr = pickServer();
  }
  return $varr;
}
```

-- but note that there's no guarantee that this doesn't go into a too long recursion. Maybe you should rather do something like this:

```
function pickServer(){
  $varr = rand(1,3);
  if($varr > 1){
    $varr = $varr + 1;
  }
  return $varr;
}
```

Comment: Works as well as the one by Nosredna, but had to think a sec.

Comment: Your second piece of code deals with the issue well. My concern with it is only that it's a bit tricky to decipher. In fact, I missed it when I was reading the answers the first time through precisely because it's non-obvious. I apologize for missing it. Had I noticed it the fist time, I would have credited you in my answer.

Comment: Update: I gave you props in my answer.

Comment: Can't remember enough PHP, but out of curiosity, could you do $varr+=$var>1; in PHP? (I know it's terrible-looking.)

Answer (score 2):

Because when the value is 2 you don't return pickserver. And the function continues to return $varr.

Answer (score 2):

```
function pickServer(){
    $varr = rand(1,4);
    if($varr==2){
        return pickServer(); //leave here
    }
    return $varr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would so something like this:

```
function pickServer()
{
$servers = array(1,3,4);
return $servers[rand(1,count($servers))]; 
}
```

Comment: I thought rand() was called with either zero or two parameters in PHP.

Comment: rand returns integers. I think this is what you were going for... return $servers[rand(1,count($servers))];

Answer (score 0):

It calls the function recursively to get another number that isn't 2, but does nothing with that result.

Try changing **pickServer()** to **return pickServer()**.

Better still, write the function iteratively so that it just loops until the value returned isn't 2.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the value...

```
function pickServer(){
$varr = rand(1,4);
if($varr==2){
    return pickServer();
}
return $varr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the recursion and remap a randomly selected 2. Simply decrease the range and map the beginning of the range (in this case 2) to 1.

```
function pickServer(){
    $varr = rand(2,4);
    if($varr==2){
        return 1;
    }
    return $varr;
}
```